# ¿Cómo separar lista en campos de un DataFrame?

Tags: r, rstudio

Tengo un lista que contiene varios campos de la siguiente forma:

```
{\"Campo1\":10000,\"Campo2\":15000",\"Campo3\":\"0\"}
```

Soy bastante nuevo con *RStudio* y me gustaría tener un DataFrame con la

```
Campo1 Campo2 Campo3
10000   15000   0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seguramente cada elemento de esa lista es una estructura del tipo [JSON Line](https://jsonlines.org/) y lo más adecuado es tratarlos como tales.

Si tienes algo como esto:

```
lista <- list('{"Campo1":10000,"Campo2":15000,"Campo3":"0"}',
              '{"Campo1":10001,"Campo2":15002,"Campo3":"1"}',
              '{"Campo1":10002,"Campo2":15003,"Campo3":"2"}')

lista

[[1]]
[1] "{\"Campo1\":10000,\"Campo2\":15000,\"Campo3\":\"0\"}"

[[2]]
[1] "{\"Campo1\":10001,\"Campo2\":15002,\"Campo3\":\"1\"}"

[[3]]
[1] "{\"Campo1\":10002,\"Campo2\":15003,\"Campo4\":\"2\"}"
```

---

Lo más simple es apoyarse en la funcionalidad de los paquetes `tidyverse` y `jsonlite`, para iterar por cada elemento de la lista y leer el objeto JSON:

```
library("tidyverse")
library("jsonlite")

lista %>% 
  map_df(fromJSON)

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  Campo1 Campo2 Campo3
   <int>  <int> <chr> 
1  10000  15000 0     
2  10001  15002 1     
3  10002  15003 2
```

---